# Animating pickerview movement with scrolling

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, picker

Currently, these are my codes to create a picker view

```
genderPicker = [[UIPickerView alloc] 
                initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 244, 320, 270)];
genderPicker.delegate = self;
genderPicker.dataSource = self;
genderPicker.tag = 1;
genderPicker.showsSelectionIndicator = TRUE;
```

The problem with this set of codes is that if the screen is scrollable, the picker would just
stay in that exact co-ordinates and will not move along with the screen when I scroll.

Could anyone assist me in animating the picker so when I scroll it up/down, the picker will follow?

Thank you.

Comment: Add the picker as a subview to the scrollview, like `[self.view addSubView:genderPicker];`, and when you're not using ARC, `[genderPicker release];`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are adding the picker, do not add it on `self.view`, instead add it on the `scrollview`.

For eg:-

```
[self.scrollview addSubView:genderPicker];
```

Here `self.scrollview` represents the `scrollview`. This will make sure that it moves along with the scrollview.